# como realizar lo que tengo en .ajax pero con un ciclo for o while

Tags: ajax

```
rowt = parseInt(1);
cantidad = parseInt(0);

 while (rowt < cantidad) {
                    $.ajax({
                                    data: "prod_cod_barra=" + $("#kits_material_"+rowt).val() + "&Accion=Producto",
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url: "modulos/almacen/kits/kits.querys.jsp",
                                    success: function (datos) {
                                        var str = datos;
                                        var unidad = parseFloat(str.split("@")[0]);
                                        var precio = parseFloat(str.split("@")[1]);
                                        alert(unidad);
                                        if (unidad == 1) {
                                            $("#kits_unidad_"+rowt).val("MX$");
                                            $("#kits_precio_"+rowt).val(precio);
                                        } else if (unidad == 2) {
                                            $("#kits_unidad_"+rowt).val("US$");
                                            $("#kits_precio_"+rowt).val(precio);
                                        } else {
                                            alert("no");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    rowt++;
                }
```

Comment: Tienes varios Ajax, no se entiende lo que quieres hacer, por favor trata de explicarlo con más claridad. Gracias.

Comment: El problema que tienes es que `rowt` vale igual para todas las respuestas porque se hacen todas las llamadas a la vez y entonces se procesan las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

no se si logre enterder bien, pero ahi enviar el valor de #kits_material 4 veces,
en ves de hacer eso crea una variable que almacene ese valor, luego crea un while

```
    var indice=0
var cantidad=4
while(indice<cantidad){
  $.ajax({aqui tu ajax})
 indice++
}
```

en cantidad puedes poner var cantidad=$('#id_donde_guardes_el_valor');

Comment: intente eso pero me crea solo el ultimo y no asigna valores por cada uno.

Comment: corregi mi codigo, habia una "i", ese valor debio ser cantidad, no si lo notaste y corregiste, pero ya que tienes $("#kits_material_"+rowt), en ves de rowt puede colocar indice